# JavaScript to Silverlight: await task based method

Tags: javascript, silverlight, asynchronous

I'm doing some research into calling Silverlight from Javascript.  I have the `scriptable` method working but this method needs to be async. As such, when I return a value, like a string, from the managed code, the actual string value does not return to the JavaScript; it's something like a `ToString` of the return type.

Is there a normal way to handle this case and "await" inside the JavaScript to unwrap the value?

Answer (score 0):

Your callable Silverlight method should take a `ScriptObject` parameter so that the JavaScript can pass in a callback. Then, you can invoke the callback, passing in the result after you finish. Something like this:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(ScriptObject callback) 
{
    var result = await SomeAsynchronousThing();
    callback.InvokeSelf(result);
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
silverlightObj.DoSomethingAsync(function(result) {
    // handle the result
});
```